# JUnit "expected" doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit

I have a wierd problem, I am trying to test a method and expecting it to throw java.util.NoSuchElementException. Here's my test code:

```
@Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testLineWithoutCommas(){
    String lineToTest = "fdgsdgfdfMarkOwenmark@mark.com";
    List<String> linesToTest = new ArrayList<String>();
    linesToTest.add(lineToTest);

    applicationChecker = new ApplicationChecker();
    applicationChecker.getLinesFromFile(linesToTest);
    applicationChecker.getDetailsFromLine(applicationChecker.getLines().get(0));
}
```

Stack trace looks as expected:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextElement(Unknown Source)
at com.scottlogic.cat.util.ApplicationChecker.getDetailsFromLine(ApplicationChecker.java:34)
at com.scottlogic.cat.utils.ApplicationCheckerTest.testLineWithoutCommas(ApplicationCheckerTest.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
and more boring stuff...
```

and finally jUnit:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
and blah blah blah...
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you getting *both* stack traces? I'd expect to see one or the other, but not both.

Comment: exactly, right? I have no idea what's wrong with it...

Comment: Lucas, he means - "how did you get them".  Not "isn't that odd".

Comment: Well this is what I am trying to figure out. I don't know. As far as I know this test should just work and that's it.

Comment: And to be more specific one of them is console output and the other is jUnit failure trace

Comment: So you've got code somewhere to print the exception to the console?  Where is it?  It wouldn't happen to be catching it, and not passing it on, would it?  That would make your JUnit test fail.

Comment: It's okay, problem solved, the first answer is right and I just did another silly mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you aren't catching and handling the NoSuchElementException somewhere in your code. The first stacktrace could be due to your code catching the exception, then logging it, and throwing it as something else, or just trapping it and not throwing it at all. the 'expected' will only catch exceptions thrown from the test itself, it doesn't deal with exceptions throws and dealt with part way through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exc = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testLineWithoutCommas(){

exc.expect(NoSuchElementException.class);
// method have exception
```

}